# Dúvida com validação do conteúdo jquery;

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um javascript que deveria executar apenas quando o conteúdo value do edit for diferente de null ou vazio, mais o mesmo está executando sempre.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                function AdicionarClasseMenuSelecionado(){
                    var menuatual = document.getElementById('MenuSelecionado').value;
                    var abaatual  = document.getElementById('AbaSelecionado').value;

                        alert(menuatual);
                        alert(abaatual);

                       //remove todos os active do cabecalho 
                       $("ul.nav.nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");
                       //remove todos os active do content 
                       $(".tab-content div").removeClass("active in");

                        //adiciona o active que retornou 
                        $("#"+menuatual).addClass("active in");
                        $("#"+abaatual).addClass("active");
                    };


                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        var menuatual = document.getElementById('MenuSelecionado').value;
                        if (menuatual != null && menuatual != undefined) {
                            AdicionarClasseMenuSelecionado();
                        } else {
                           alert("não foi enviado nenhum menu");
                        }      
                    });
    </script>
```

Html:

```
<input name="MenuSelecionado" type="hidden"  value="null" id="MenuSelecionado">
<input name="AbaSelecionado" type="hidden"  value="null" id="AbaSelecionado">
```

Comment: `ou vazio`, não falou por exemplo um `|| menuatual == ""` para validar se está vazio? `null` e `undefined` são diferentes de vazio

Comment: Cara, não é muito legal misturar a sintaxe do **Javascript** com a do **jQuery**.

Answer (score 0):

Veja os valores abaixo:

```
// false
var menuatual = 0; // zero é false

// true
var menuatual = 1; // número diferente de zero não é false

// false
var menuatual; // undefined é false porque não tem valor atribuído

// true
var menuatual = "0"; // string (mesmo o zero) não é false    

// false
var menuatual = ""; // vazio é false, mas não é null nem undefined

// true
var menuatual = " "; // espaço é string, não é false
```

Analisando a sua comparação:

```
menuatual != null && menuatual != undefined
```

Você está dizendo que `menuatual` não pode ser *null* e também não pode ser *undefined*. Então se for vazio (`menuatual == ''`) irá validar, porque vazio não é *null* nem *undefined*.

O que você precisa fazer é apenas verificar se a variável `menuatual` é *true* simplesmente colocando apenas ela no `if`:

```
if(menuatual){
   // menuatual é true
   // ou seja, não é vazio, não é null, não é undefined
   // e não é o número zero (0 é diferente de "0")
}else{
   // menuatual é false
}
```

Ou seja, você espera que a variável não seja *undefined*, *null*, vazia ou o número 0.